# Standard for date format: NOT numerical

Tags: date, standards

For dates as numbers we have an excellent international standard (ISO8601).

But is there a international standard for dates *not* written as numbers? (Something like "January 8, 2016").

Let me just stress: ISO8601 is *not* an answer to this question. ISO8601 deals with dates as numbers.

Comment: IMHO - beyond the realm of (arabic) numbers - language specific text like "January" will probably never become an international standard.

Comment: But we _do_ see it with phonetic alphabet: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet - even with minor national changes for special letters like æ, ø and å.